# Does every connected set that is not a line segment cross some dyadic square?

Tags: geometry, discrete-geometry, euclidean-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry

A *dyadic square* is a subset of $R^2$ of the form $x + 2^{-n} [0,1]^2$ with $x \in 2^{-m} Z^2$, for integers $m,n \geq 0$. We say that a set $A$ *crosses* a square $S$ if there exists a connected subset of $A \cap S$ which intersects two opposite sides of the square $S$. Clearly, the 45 degree line $\{ (\pi + t, t) : t \in R \}$ does not cross any dyadic square. Does every non-trivial closed, connected set that is not a line segment cross some dyadic square?

Comment: I would have expected the condition $m\le n$. Is that what you mean? Or is this another version of the problem? Every line segment that is not $\pm45$ degrees, and every sufficiently smooth curve that is not a $\pm45$ degree line segment must cross a dyadic square (even with the strong definition of dyadic square). So if there are counterexamples they are pretty pathological.

Comment: I think that every path-connected component of such a non-crossing set should be a line segment.

Comment: Gunter Rote, I do not mean the condition $m\leq n$. E.g. the square $[1/8,5/8]\times [1/4,3/4]$ is a dyadic square with my definition. Perhaps you would like to call such a square a translated dyadic square.

Comment: There used to be an interesting answer posted here. Where is it? Was it wrong?

Comment: Hi Gunter, I pointed out that there were two mistakes in this answer. A day later it was removed by somebody.

Comment: Hello Kevin, this is a nice question and seems difficult, though I came up with some ideas that I need to develop. Do you know if it is an open question, and if anyone has done work on it, any references? Did you find it somewhere in a book or a paper, or did you come up with it on your own? I am inclined to believe that there is no example, though I changed my mind about it several times yesterday and today. I will email a colleague whose area is closer to this question, to see if he knows anything or has any advice (just sending him the link to your question as posted here). Thank you,

Comment: Is it pure curiosity? In other words --- do you have some motivation for this question?

Comment: I believe I have a positive answer under the additional assumption that the set in question is path-connected. I posted a related question which eventually got a bit long, but see the definition of *hsb* plane continuum there, at the beginning, along with the Result after the "Edit May 29-31, 2023" here: https://mathoverflow.net/q/446092 . For completeness, here are a couple of other, related questions that I posted recently https://mathoverflow.net/q/446317 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4694709 . (I don't feel like posting my "path-connected" solution here, it is only a special case.)

Comment: @Mirko: do you think that you can prove it for pseudo-arcs?

Comment: @IanAgol No, I don't have a proof for the pseudoarc, though this is usually what I think of, as a totally path-disconnected continuum (i.e. path-components are points). If $C$ is say hereditarily indecomposable plane continuum I have considered (something elementary), take $\frac1n$-neighborhood (union of all $\frac1n$-balls with centers in $C$) this is path-connected, try to use it somehow (then let $n\to\infty$), but haven't had much success. Your comment reminded me that the pseudoarc is arc-like(chainable), so perhaps use this to modify the path-connected case, but I have to think about it

Comment: Really, some zero-span curve can't be constructed with just a uniform direct limit by oscillating off corners in Koch curve style with rectilinear paths by like a scaled factor of $> \frac{1}{4^n}$?  In my head it works, the argument should go like 'what's the biggest dyadic square it crosses' and then induct.  Has anyone tried to write it down?  In my head it works.  If there is no example then a dimension theorist probably can handwave why, you should tag dimension theory and GMT.

Comment: Since you @mirko don't mind rephrasing-reposting the question I'd repost as a dimension/measure-theoretical question on curves in the plane, someone will spit some result at you really quick if you're convinced it's true.  But I think it's false, you should be able to get good control of limiting behavior with a rectilinear construction and finish using basic results about direct limits of continua.